# godot AI pong movement is clunky

Tags: artificial-intelligence, pong, godot

i'm new to godot and am making a pong game to practice, i tried making an AI and it works but the movement is extremely clunky when the ball gets near the paddle
here's my code:

````
var direction: = Vector2(0.0,0.0)
var velocity:= Vector2(0.0,0.0)

Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready() -> void:
pass

Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func physicsprocess(delta: float) -> void:
position.x = 135
var ball = getparent().getnode("ball").position
if ball.y < position.y:
direction.y = -1
velocity = speed * direction
moveandslide(velocity)
elif ball.y > position.y:
direction.y = 1
velocity = speed * direction
moveandslide(velocity)```
````

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you don't repeat the following code?

```
velocity = speed * direction
moveandslide(velocity)
```

Also, I'm assuming the speed of the paddle is faster than the speed of the ball, in which case you're going to get a stuttering effect when the paddle closes in on the ball and creates this loop:

paddle passes the ball
paddle changes direction
ball passes the paddle
paddle changes direction... and so on.

I haven't tested this but if you adjust your code slightly, this could fix the issue:

`if ball.y < (position.y - speed):` and `elif ball.y > (position.y + speed)`

As I say, I haven't tested this so you might have to change the signs but that should hopefully stop the jerkiness.